# Trigger that excludes some words

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger, check-constraints

I have a question related to database triggers in T-SQL.

I want to create a trigger that allows only specific words (available, not available) to a column `avalability`.

How it could be done?

I understand what trigger is, but lost in the sequence of commands - what should come after what.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - BEFORE INSERT Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014056/sql-server-before-insert-trigger)

Comment: Not sure that you really need a trigger, why not create a `CHECK` constraint on the concerned column?

Comment: You need a `before insert` trigger. There are plenty of examples via Goggle. Or what @GMB suggests.

Comment: This definitely sounds like you're describing `CHECK CONSTRAINT` not a `TRIGGER`.

Comment: A trigger is absolutely the wrong tool for this job. Use a check constraint.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure that a trigger is really needed here. Another solution would be to create a `CHECK` constraint on the concerned column, like:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT availability_check CHECK (availability IN ('available', 'not available'));
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=74377e56909192152a7acdc26e89cbce)**:

```
CREATE TABLE TableName (availability VARCHAR(20) );

ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT availability_check CHECK (availability IN ('available', 'not available'));

INSERT INTO TableName(availability) VALUES('foo');

-- Error
Msg 547 Level 16 State 0 Line 1
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "availability_check". The conflict occurred in database "fiddle_325b8b256056466caf52aa4bb7467fd7", table "dbo.TableName", column 'availability'.
Msg 3621 Level 0 State 0 Line 1
The statement has been terminated.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can `ALTER` your table and add a `CHECK Constraint` directly as

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableName
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Avalability CHECK(Avalability IN('Available', 'Not Available'));
```

Note that this will throw an error if there is some data already inserted in the table and doesn't match and conflicted with the `CHECK Constraint`.

If you don't `CREATE` your table yet, then you could use

```
CREATE TABLE YourTableName(
  Availability VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Avalability CHECK(Availability IN('Available', 'Not Available')) 
);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches to the problem.

1. **GO FOR: CHECK CONSTRAINT BASED APPROACH**: You can achieve it simply using CHECK Constraint. It makes the job simpler, as @GMB has already mentioned in his answer.

```sql
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Table1_Availability CHECK (Availability IN ('Available', 'Not Available'))
```

2. **DON'T GO FOR : TRIGGER BASED APPROACH**: If you want to create trigger, you can create INSTEAD OF TRIGGER as given below. Also, you should create similar INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger also, to take care of UPDATE scenarios. But, this is a circuitous approach. See the amount of code required, corresponding maintenance.

```sql
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_availability_insert]
        ON [dbo].[Table1]
        INSTEAD OF INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (inserted.Availability IN ('available', 'not available'))
    BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Table1(Id, Availability)
    SELECT Id, Availability FROM inserted
    END

    COMMIT;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
         ROLLBACK

    RETURN;
    END CATCH
```

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_availability_update]
        ON [dbo].[Table1]
        INSTEAD OF UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (inserted.Availability IN ('available', 'not available'))
    BEGIN 
    UPDATE Table1
    SET Availability = inserted.Availability
    WHERE Table1.Id = inserted.Id;
    END

    COMMIT;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
         ROLLBACK

    RETURN;
    END CATCH
```

Comment: It's possible to do with a trigger, but: 1. You'll have to write similar code for when a user attempts to update the column. 2. You'll have to provide insert / update statements for all columns in the table inside your triggers. That's not a terrible problem but it's something that makes maintenance of the database harder.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Agree with you. I just provided the code, so that he can understand the amount of work involved. I have also mentioned that again he has to write INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger. I myself recommend CHECK Constraint only.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I have updated my answer to clarify the amount of effort needed

Comment: `IF (inserted.Availability IN ('available', 'not available')` has unbalanced parentheses and it isn't clear how it checks all rows in `inserted`. `UPDATE Table1(Availability) SET Availability = inserted.Availability` is also a bit mysterious as to how it selects data from `inserted`, but at least it updates _all_ rows in the table since there is no `where` clause.

Comment: @HABO, thanks for catching the issue. corrected them. I just wanted to mention the complexity of the effort. OP did not provide table schema and all. Just mentioned the effort.

Answer (score 1):

A CHECK constraint is the way I'd go. Another approach is to use referential constraints, AKA Primary and Foreign keys. If "available" and "not available" are used in multiple places this will be better than a CHECK constraint because you can enforce the same rules across multiple tables. This way you can enforce consistency and avoid having some tables with the other values like "available" and "unavailable".

```
-- Lookup table for all possible "Availability" values
CREATE TABLE dbo.LU_Availability
(
  AvailabilityPK VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_LU_Availability PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(AvailabilityPK)
);
INSERT dbo.LU_Availability (AvailabilityPK) VALUES ('Available'),('Not Available');

-- Table with the allowable values enforced via foriegn key constraint
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
(
  someId         INT IDENTITY,
  someValue      CHAR(10),
  [Availability] VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_AvailabilityTxt FOREIGN KEY([Availability]) 
    REFERENCES dbo.LU_Availability(AvailabilityPK)
);

INSERT dbo.YourTable ([Availability]) VALUES ('Available');     -- Succeeds
INSERT dbo.YourTable ([Availability]) VALUES ('NOT Available'); -- Succeeds
INSERT dbo.YourTable ([Availability]) VALUES ('Perhaps');       -- Fails
```

Lastly - it's important to understand that, while constraints (CHECK, PK, FK, UNIQUE) will slow things down a little, triggers are performance killers. This is why experienced developers and DBAs suggest avoiding them when a constraint will do the trick.